# What is better for perfomance width="100%" or left="0" right="0"?

Tags: performance, apache-flex, mxml

In latest Adobe Flex sdk 4.6, what is better from performance view?

```
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

or

```
<s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really know, but I'm fairly certain the difference would be marginal at best.

Comment: I Don't even know how you would test that; and I suspect there are many factors that could be involved.  What is the layout type?  What are the children of the group?  Width and Height--or in your case percentWidth and percentHeight--are properties, while left/right/top/bottom are styles. Setting the left/right/top/bottom will never bypass the measure method; however setting the width and height will.  I'm not sure about setting the percentWidth and percentHeight, though. MXML uses smoke and mirrors to set the percentWidth & percentHeight; which is exactly what your code will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `BasicLayout.updateDisplayList()` i found this (in loop for every child element):

```
if (!isNaN(percentWidth))
            {
                var availableWidth:Number = unscaledWidth;
                if (!isNaN(left))
                    availableWidth -= left;
                if (!isNaN(right))
                     availableWidth -= right;

                childWidth = Math.round(availableWidth * Math.min(percentWidth * 0.01, 1));
                elementMaxWidth = Math.min(layoutElement.getMaxBoundsWidth(),
                    maxSizeToFitIn(unscaledWidth, hCenter, left, right, layoutElement.getLayoutBoundsX()));
            }
            else if (!isNaN(left) && !isNaN(right))
            {
                childWidth = unscaledWidth - right - left;
            }
```

And same for height.

So, looks like:

1. *percenWidth* has higher priority than *top* and *left* (if both are set)
2. ***top*** and *left* calculated easier than *percenWidth* (single subtraction against round, functions call and conditions)
3. *top* and *left* may be used as styles declarations.

Also, most of Flex4 skins are based *top* and *left* - i think for performance  reason too.

Comment: Nice post. one more thing to say is that left will tell component the distance from the left side of parent. The percent width will just tell how much of the parent it will take in width. Depending on the case you use it, you MAY end in different results.